# Setting up different endpoint ports with NancyFx and ASP.NET core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nancy, endpoint

I'm looking into the documentation and can't seem to find any information on this.

Anyways, is it possible for an ASP.NET core application to set up Nancy endpoints to use different ports?

**Example**:

- NancyModule1 => 5000
- NancyModule2 => 5001

The reason being is that I am hosting different APIs that need to be accessed through specific ports.

Comment: Not sure how Nancy comes into it, but when you start an asp.net core server on multiple ports they all feed into the same application pipeline. That said, you can start two application instances side by side in the same process.

Comment: I wonder if it makes sense using the same server with 2 different bindings then blocking requests to the NancyModule based on the incoming port or some other configuration. 

Hosting 2 different servers is a bit heavy as all services and middleware will be duplicated